# Directfb 1.6.3 Could not set the gamma ramp --> Invalid argument

Tags: c, debian, directfb

I am trying to run an application on a Debian Machine. The application is written in C and is using DirectFb. But the directfb part is not working. It gives an error saying "**Could not set the gamma ramp --> Invalid argument**".[image]I have attached the screen shot.

Comment: I think it would be good if you go under the hood and see what is actually happening ... What I can guess is that some ioctl is getting called which it not supported or does not support the arguments by the driver.

Comment: Yes. I have seen the code :

FBDEV_IOCTL( FBIOPUTCMAP, cmap ).

          

  I don't get the documentation  for this function as well.

So I am unable to understand this. One information I want to give is that, my display is 1920x1080 while the picture 768x1024. So I am not sure this might be the problem.

Comment: Can you debug the ioctl function (I mean if it can be recompiled by putting some prints in there) it would be very easy to find the problem ... otherwise it might get hectic .. well 1024x768 (XGA) is a popular mode and it should be supported on higher resolution displays ... Search for your display model and see if that is supported or not ... If its connected through HDMI or DVI they communicate with the driver over I2c for supported video modes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will keep you updated.

Comment: Sorry, but to say that the application is written in C is no sense here, if you don't have access to the source code.  Help cannot be given with no access to the source code, as it is impossible to verify what the argument value is.  And the error is not that. the error is (!!!) marked and says 768x1024 is not a valid resolution, most probably you have switched values and wanted 1024x768 instead for resolution, somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @LuisColorado the switched resolution parameters can be a cause ..

Comment: Hi @LuisColorado I just switched the dimensions. Thanks for your advice. But still its not loading an image and have blank output. Is segmentation fault has to do something with this.

Comment: @user3909276, Because that's the screen mode what you are trying to configure, not the canvas size (which probably will have to be the window size you allow the window to grow)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your application with different arguments , It will provide you the actual reason , why It is giving segmentation fault: 
./tkcoda -c /var/tk/tk.conf -d --dfb:pixelformat=ARGB,system=fbdev,depth=16,mode=1024x768

you can check differnt pixelformat e.g. ARGB , RGB32 etc, for system fbdev , omap etc, for depth=32 , 16 etc , mode is your display width e.g. 640x480 etc.

Try to check your Font directory also , your font file is present or not at specified location .